# client makes multiple connections to server

Tags: c, network-programming

I have updated my code to this based on research:

```
while (number_of_connections--) {
    client_sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);

    if (connect(client_sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect failed. Error");
    }

    printf("socket %d created\n", client_sock);

    pthread_t sniffer_thread;
    new_sock = malloc(1);
    *new_sock = client_sock;

    if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0)
    {
        perror("could not create thread");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Then I'm handling it with this function:

```
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    //Get the socket descriptor
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size, cursor;
    char *message , client_message[2000];

    //Send some messages to the client
    char handshakeBuf[sizeof(handshake)];
    memcpy(handshakeBuf, &handshake, sizeof(handshake));

    handshake.a++;
    handshake.c = 0xac;
    handshake.d = 0x0d;

    //Send some data
    if( send(sock , handshakeBuf , sizeof(handshakeBuf) , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("Send failed");
    }

    //keep communicating with server
    while(1)
    {
        //Receive a reply from the server
        if( recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("recv failed");
            break;
        }

        puts(client_message);
    }

    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

Now my problem is why does it suddenly stop when it reaches the 4th connection?

### Original Question

I am trying to write my first C client. I needed to create 4 connections to the server from one client to simulate 4 clients connected where each connection of course has its own handler.

Here is what I have so far:

```
void connect_to_server(struct sockaddr_in server);

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int number_of_connections, x;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("ipaddress");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( port );

    number_of_connections = 4;

    for ( x = 0; x < number_of_connections; x++ ) {
        connect_to_server(server);
    }

    return 0;
}

void connect_to_server(struct sockaddr_in server) {
    int sock;

    char message[1000] , server_reply[2000];

    sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    if (connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect failed. Error");
    }

    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%s" , message);

        if( send(sock , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("Send failed");
        }

        if( recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("recv failed");
            break;
        }

        puts(server_reply);
    }

    close(sock);
}
```

Well I'm obviously also new to C. So what is wrong? Should I declare more sockets like: `int sockA, sockB, sockC, sockD` or I guess its the `while loop` inside the `connect_to_server`?

Comment: What do you mean by "it suddenly stop"? What specific behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: Could you please show the implementation of `main()` function for the **current question** (such implementation are already provided for the **original question**)?

Comment: amongst other things, when a system call fails, dont keep executing that same sequence of code.  suggest, at each failure calling perror() so get the full story (on stderr) as to why it failed.  and then stop executing that sequence, perhaps as drastically as calling exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

Comment: to keep it simple, use one socket per connection.

Comment: Fix this one: "malloc(1)". One byte in not enough for holding int value. It may work with luck.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the new version of the implementation uses multithreading: `pthread_create(...)` function call. But is there an implementation of waiting after the threads are created?

For example, the waiting can be implemented:

- by using `pthread_join(...)` function call;
- by waiting for specific key press event using `getchar()` function call.

### Notes

Please be careful with these statements:

```
if (send(sock, handshakeBuf, sizeof(handshakeBuf), 0) < 0)
if (recv(sock, client_message, 2000 , 0) < 0)
```

The `send()` and `recv()` functions do not guarantee that the entire buffer will be sent/received after one function call. The functions return the actual number of sent/received bytes.

Please introduce analysis of the returned value for `send()` and `recv()` function calls: continue sending if not all bytes are sent, continue receiving if "not enough" bytes are received. Also, there is an article related to the some basics of the network programming: [TCP/IP client-server application: exchange with string messages](http://brunov.info/blog/2013/02/09/tcpip-client-server-application-exchange-with-string-messages/).

Comment: I haven't implemented the boundaries or framing yet just trying to get the skeleton up first. Thanks though, will look into this now.

Comment: @majidarif, could you please post the result?